# Rust TCP Proxy to pipe http, ssh and other tcp traffic

Tags: tcp, server, proxy, rust

I am new to rust and as learning project I want to create a tcp proxy. Tokio overwhelmed me and I could not find the proper documentation to understand how it works. So I tried to go with std net modules but I stuck at properly piping the traffic. I bound multiple listeners in their own threads and want to pipe the traffic forth and back like a proper tcp proxy would do. Unfortunately I seem to don't understand how that has to work in Rust. Can someone give me an example without 3rd party dependencies?

Here is my code.  handle_connection gets called from accepting the connection.

```
fn forward(direction: &str, input: &mut BufReader<TcpStream>, output: &mut BufWriter<TcpStream>) {
    loop {
        let mut buffer = [0;1024];
        debug!("{} Reading", direction);
        match input.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(bytes) => {
                debug!("Read {} bytes", bytes);
                if bytes < 1  {
                    break;
                }
                match output.write_all(&mut buffer) {
                    Ok(_) => {
                        debug!("Forwarded {:#?} bytes", bytes);
                        output.flush();
                        if bytes < 1024 {
                            break; // abort when everything is sent
                        }
                    },
                    Err(error) => panic!("Could not forward: {}", error)
                }
            },
            Err(error) => panic!("Could not read: {}", error)
        }
    }
}

fn handle_connection(mapping: ProxyMapping, incoming: TcpStream) -> Result<(), String> {
    info!("Incoming connection from {}", incoming.peer_addr().map_err(|e| format!("{}", e))?);
    // Try to connect to target
    let outgoing = TcpStream::connect_timeout(
        &mapping.get_target_addr()?,
        Duration::from_secs(1)
    )?;

    // forward tcp steam
    debug!("Start sync");
    let input_clone = input.try_clone()
        .map_err(|error| format!("Couldn't clone {}", error))?;
    let mut input_read = BufReader::new(input);
    let mut input_write = BufWriter::new(input_clone);

    let output_clone = output.try_clone()
        .map_err(|error| format!("Couldn't clone {}", error))?;
    let mut output_read = BufReader::new(output);
    let mut output_write = BufWriter::new(output_clone);
    debug!("spawn sync");

    loop {
        debug!("Forward");
        forward("forward", &mut input_read, &mut output_write);
        debug!("Backward");
        forward("backward",&mut output_read, &mut input_write);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

So far it proxies some data but for http requests it stops at backward reading as I don't know yet when I should shutdown a connection. After some time it just floods the log with read 0 bytes. I added a loop for the sync as for one tcp connection multiple packets could be sent. Any ideas how to improve this?

Comment: Have you found a better solution for this?

Comment: Indeed I finished my project. I think you can find the related code here https://github.com/fragsalat/awake-on-proxy/blob/master/src/proxy.rs#L29